# Keep text field and button inside box

Tags: html, css

I've got a simple problem that I swear I've done a hundred times but I guess I need another pair of eyes.

I have a table, enter email text field and an add-email button all in a box. When I add more emails to the table it pushes out the text field and button outside of the box. The text field and button need to be side by side.

```
<div class="cc_halfblock">
        <div class="dropshadow">
            <div class="dropshadow-heading">
                Heading
            </div>


    <form id="emailform" name="emailform" method="POST">
        <table class="cc_table">
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                                foo@bar.com
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email"
                                    value="Delete" title="Delete this email" 
                            </button>
                            <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

...
                </tbody>
            </table>
           </form>


            <div class="cc_margintop">
            <form id="addemailform" name="addemailform" method="POST">
                    <div class="cc_separator">
                        <input type="text" size="24" maxlength="64" name="add_email" placeholder="Enter email" id="add_email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="cc_separator">
                        <button class="addbutton cc_button_enable pull-right" name="submitemail">Add Email</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cc_emailerrors"></div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.cc_button_enable {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.dropshadow-heading {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #28292A;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.dropshadow-body {
    padding: 1px 15px 15px 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.dropshadow {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.cc_table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    table-layout: auto;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* display:inline-block; */
    width: 100%;
}

.cc_table th 
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(230, 230, 230);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    color: rgb(165, 165, 165);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.cc_table td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 8px;
}

.cc_table tr:hover td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #a8cb17;
    color: #333399;
}

/* Used for spacing between form fields and buttons */
.cc_separator {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
/* generic spacing for divs on top */
.cc_margintop {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#addemailform label.error {
        color: red;
        display: block;
}


/* generic float left */
.cc_floatleft {
    float: left;
}


/* blocks used for main content */
.cc_halfblock {
    width:45%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

Fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/rkkw6uvg/1/

Comment: you mean that if you add more emails on the same row/td, the table stretches?

Comment: @Crispy-George No if you add more rows of emails it pushes out the text field and button. See the fiddle it shows the text field and button outside the box.

Comment: still not clear, what you are asking.

Comment: @Tom oooh, you mean that add-email button and enter email text-field? if so, clear your floats :) add .cc_margintop{overflow: hidden} or some clearfix on it

Comment: @Crispy-George I couldn't clear floats they are needed for positioning the field and button side by side but overflow hidden seems to have done the job! Thanks. You should post so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some floating elements inside `.cc_margintop`, so they'll break their parents bouds and cause a mess.

You need to clear those floats, so here are some possible solutions depending on your requirements:

- add a `overflow:hidden` rule on `.cc_margintop`
- use a good old clearfix method on `.cc_margintop` like so:

Check out **[the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/m2qk5v6n/1/)** and the clearfix bellow:

```
.cc_margintop:after{
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
.cc_button_enable {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 float: left;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.dropshadow-heading {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #28292A;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.dropshadow-body {
    padding: 1px 15px 15px 15px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.dropshadow {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
 min-height: 200px;
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.cc_table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    table-layout: auto;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* display:inline-block; */
    width: 100%;
}

.cc_table th 
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(230, 230, 230);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    color: rgb(165, 165, 165);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.cc_table td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 8px;
}

.cc_table tr:hover td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #a8cb17;
    color: #333399;
}

/* Used for spacing between form fields and buttons */
.cc_separator {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
/* generic spacing for divs on top */
.cc_margintop {
 margin-top: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;/*clear those pesky floats*/
}

#addemailform label.error {
        color: red;
        display: block;
}


/* generic float left */
.cc_floatleft {
 float: left;
}


/* blocks used for main content */
.cc_halfblock {
 width:45%;
 float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc_halfblock">
  <div class="dropshadow">
   <div class="dropshadow-heading">
    Heading
   </div>


 <form id="emailform" name="emailform" method="POST">
  <table class="cc_table">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
        foo@bar.com
         </td>
      <td>
       <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email"
         value="Delete" title="Delete this email" 
       </button>
       <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
      </td>
     </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
      <td>
        foo1@bar.com
         </td>
      <td>
       <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email"
         value="Delete" title="Delete this email" 
       </button>
       <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
      </td>
     </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
      <td>
        foo2@bar.com
         </td>
      <td>
       <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email"
         value="Delete" title="Delete this email" 
       </button>
       <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
      </td>
     </tr>
                                
                                <tr>
      <td>
        foo3@bar.com
         </td>
      <td>
       <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email"
         value="Delete" title="Delete this email" 
       </button>
       <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
      </td>
     </tr>
                                    
                                    <tr>
      <td>
        foo4@bar.com
         </td>
      <td>
       <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email"
         value="Delete" title="Delete this email" 
       </button>
       <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
      </td>
     </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
           </form>


   <div class="cc_margintop">
   <form id="addemailform" name="addemailform" method="POST">
     <div class="cc_separator">
      <input type="text" size="24" maxlength="64" name="add_email" placeholder="Enter email" id="add_email" />
     </div>
     <div class="cc_separator">
      <button class="addbutton cc_button_enable pull-right" name="submitemail">Add Email</button>
     </div>
     <div id="cc_emailerrors"></div>
   </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below code.

1. Tag `<input type='button' />` is self closing, don't use `<button></button`>
2. Pay attention on the class `dropshadow`. I added `clear: both;` and `display: inline-block;` to solve your specific problem.

```css
.cc_button_enable {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 float: left;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.dropshadow-heading {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #28292A;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.dropshadow-body {
    padding: 1px 15px 15px 15px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.dropshadow {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
 /* min-height: 290px; */
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.cc_table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    table-layout: auto;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* display:inline-block; */
    width: 100%;
}

.cc_table th 
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(230, 230, 230);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    color: rgb(165, 165, 165);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.cc_table td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 8px;
}

.cc_table tr:hover td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #a8cb17;
    color: #333399;
}

/* Used for spacing between form fields and buttons */
.cc_separator {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
/* generic spacing for divs on top */
.cc_margintop {
 margin-top: 25px;
}

#addemailform label.error {
        color: red;
        display: block;
}


/* generic float left */
.cc_floatleft {
 float: left;
}


/* blocks used for main content */
.cc_halfblock {
 width:45%;
 float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc_halfblock">
  <div class="dropshadow">
   <div class="dropshadow-heading">
    Heading
   </div>


 <form id="emailform" name="emailform" method="POST">
     <table class="cc_table">
   <tr>
    <td>foo@bar.com</td>
    <td>
                    <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email" value="Delete" title="Delete this email" />
     <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
    </td>
   </tr> 
            <tr>
     <td>foo1@bar.com</td>
     <td>
                <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email" value="Delete" title="Delete this email" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
     </td>
        </tr>          
            <tr>
    <td>foo2@bar.com</td>
    <td>
                    <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email" value="Delete" title="Delete this email" />
     <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
    </td>
   </tr>
            <tr>
    <td>foo3@bar.com</td>
    <td>
                    <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email" value="Delete" title="Delete this email" />
     <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
    </td>
   </tr>
            <tr>
    <td>foo4@bar.com</td>
    <td>
     <button class="deletebutton cc_icon_button" name="delete_email" value="Delete" title="Delete this email" />
     <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="" />
                </td>
   </tr>
        </table>
    </form>


 <div class="cc_margintop">
  <form id="addemailform" name="addemailform" method="POST">
   <div class="cc_separator">
    <input type="text" size="24" maxlength="64" name="add_email" placeholder="Enter email" id="add_email" />
   </div>
   <div class="cc_separator">
    <div class="addbutton cc_button_enable pull-right" name="submitemail">Add Email</div>
   </div>
   <div id="cc_emailerrors"></div>
  </form>
 </div>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Answer: `http://jsfiddle.net/rkkw6uvg/2/`

I took out two floats and didn't even need to clear anything.

First float I took out was in this class: `.cc_button_enable`
Second: In the class: `.cc_separator`